# Cannot resolve constructor 'Factory(com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter)'

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am building an app and using Exoplayer dependencies version 2.16.1 and I am, trying to retrieve videos I uploaded to my database, while following a tutorial on this process, I am making use of this code to Implement Exoplayer

```
 BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder(activity).build();
                DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
```

At this junction I get an error saying "Cannot resolve constructor 'Factory(com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter)'"

The code I am using as a guide looks like this

```
try {


                BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder(activity).build();
                DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
                exoPlayer = (SimpleExoPlayer) ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(activity);
                
                
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
```

And I guess the person used version 2.10.8 but I cant use this version as it is not compatible with the Gradle version I am using. How can i correct the code since I am using Exoplayer 2.16.1

Answer (score 0):

It is because version 2.10.8 is using the *deprecated* SimpleExoPlayer class.

[image]

`implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.16.1'`

```
exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
            exoplayer?.{otherconfigs...}
```